# Cannot get latex Output for the code below

Tags: python, sympy, physics, differential-equations

I am following this video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dkifb6nytao to get general solution for a differential equation.

```py
from sympy.interactive import printing
printing.init_printing(use_latex = True)
from sympy import *
import sympy as sp

v = sp.Symbol('v')
u = sp.Function('u')(v)
```

In the tutorial the guy gets the latex format printing upon running the code ie. u(v) in output. How do i get that as well.

Comment: have you printed u? just add print(u) at the end of the code

Comment: What environment are you using to run sympy? Is it a Jupyter notebook, Spyder, vscode etc?

Comment: I'm running it on google colab

Comment: @darthbaba using display(u) solves the problem thanks